# Why "on" is the only preposition for "weekdays"? Why not "in"?

Tags: prepositions

Everywhere I have read that the correct preposition is **on** for weekdays.

Would it still be OK to say: "Monday is the hardest **in** weekdays"?

Comment: No, it would not be OK. Not only would it be wrong; it would make no sense.

Comment: You could say, "Monday is the hardest weekday."; "Monday is the hardest of all weekdays."; even *possibly* "Monday is the hardest *among* weekdays." [not "*in* weekdays"] (But that last one sounds kind of weird, and it would be better as, "Monday is the hardest among all the weekdays.") .... "Why?" is sometimes a question no one can answer when it comes to language.

Comment: We would more naturally say "Monday is the hardest weekday", but if you must use a partitive phrase, then "Monday is the hardest of the weekdays" would be fine.

Comment: @YasinO - We appreciate your gratitude,, but please read through [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/are-thanks-for-the-answers-unnecessary). That way, you'll know why some of your comments keep disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence makes no sense.

I assume you mean:

> Monday **is the** hardest weekday

That would mean you are very busy on Monday and it is the hardest day that is a weekday.

You could also say

> Monday is the hardest **of the weekdays**.

or even

> Monday is the hardest **of weekdays**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, it better be "hardest of all weekdays". But still I'm inclined to say  "Monday is the hardest of the weekdays" . I don't why . By trying "in", I think, I wanted to reach "among" or "in its category, group, etc" .

Comment: I don't know where this notion comes from that the sentence "makes no sense" (said in this answer, and said once in the comments, too). Sure, it's not idiomatic, and it sounds off to me, also, but I can still make sense of it. Maybe I've had enough set theory in my past to get it? To my ear, the OP's sentence reads like: "Monday is the hardest in (the set of) weekdays." Of course _of_ would be better, and my preferred wording might have no preposition at all (_Monday is the hardest weekday_), but "makes no sense" seems a bit harsh. We don't parse English like a compiler parses code.